# Makefile - require all pattern matches

Tags: makefile, wildcard

I'm trying to write a rule that will call my checking script on the output of each stage of my program, generating that output if it does not already exist using my `%.output : %.input` rule.

I tried `check : $(wildcard stage[1234].output)` but this causes the rule to require only those matching output files that *already exist*.

I could just define a variable like `TARGETS = stage1.output stage2.output ...`, but is there a way to generate all possible matches of a pattern and then require them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the `%.output : %.input` rule to apply, you need both

1. a goal that requires an intermediate that matches the pattern `%.output`
2. a corresponding `%.input` file - either preexisting or a rule to build it

If your `stage*.input` files already exist, you can use:

```
INPUTS=$(wildcard stage[1234].input)
TARGETS=$(INPUTS:%.input=%.output)
check: $(TARGETS)
```

If your `stage*.input` files don't exist but are expected to be built from similar pattern rules, reapply the same principle.

If your `stage*.input` are produced from more complicated means, but assuming that their name can be generated by the application of a substitution pattern simply apply that pattern. In your example it would be something like:

```
L:= 1 2 3 4
TARGETS=$(L:%=stage%.output)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want analogue of `seq` Unix utility in Make, here it is:

```
seq = $(if $(word $1,$2),$2,$(call seq,$1,$2 $(words $2 1)))
$(info seq(10)=$(call seq,10))

stage_sount:=7
stages:=$(patsubst %,stage%.output,$(call seq,$(stage_sount)))
$(info stages=$(stages))
all:
```

Output:

```
$ make
seq(10)= 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
stages=stage1.output stage2.output stage3.output stage4.output stage5.output stage6.output stage7.output
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```